# OnNavigatedFrom not fired after upgrade to Prism.Forms 6.3.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

After upgrading to Prism.Forms 6.3.0 (from Prism 6.2.0) OnNavigatedFrom is no longer triggered when leaving a page (NavigationService.NavigateAsync from MasterDetailViewModel). Tested on iOS.

I am using version XF version 2.3.4.267. Is there any changes from 6.2.0 to 6.3.0 that could influence such an behaviour? Have I just stumbled upon a bug?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed in that area of the code base.  When navigating from a MasterDetail, you don't leave the MasterDetail so it won't call OnNavigatedFrom.  It simply updated the Detail to the target page.  When the detail page changes the INavAware methods will be called on the detail page.

Comment: @ Brian, thanks for the quick reply. Must be something else then, though I am  facing the same problems in all my view models when I try to navigate away from them. Will try to see if im able to create a repro.